# TortoiseSVN and subversion's global-ignores

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm having problems convincing TortoiseSVN to respect my subversion repository's `svn:global-ignores` property.  No matter what I've tried, it still lists all the supposed-to-be-ignored files as unversioned and available to commit.

My `svn:global-ignores` string, set on the root of the repository (note the `bin` and `obj` in towards the end):

```
*.o *.lo .la ## .*.rej .rej .~ ~ .# .DS_Store thumbs.db Thumbs.db *.bak *.class *.exe *.dll *.mine *.obj *.ncb *.lib *.log *.idb *.pdb *.ilk .msi .res *.pch *.suo *.exp ~. cvs CVS .CVS .cvs release Release debug Debug ignore Ignore bin Bin obj Obj *.csproj.user *.user _ReSharper.* *.resharper.user
```

A screenshot of my commit window:

[image: problematical commit window]

What can I do to keep all these `bin` and `obj` folders from showing up?  On a previous machine, I used TortoiseSVN's global ignore property, but I want these files to be ignored for all developers without having to remember to set that field on each new machine we set up.  Am I misunderstanding what SVN's `global-ignores` does?

Comment: Hm, AFAIK, `global-ignores` belong in _your_ subversion config, not as a property of the checkout. Under Windows, probably in something like `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.subversion\config` (no Windows here, can't check).

Comment: Read *carefully* http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/repository-dictated-configuration-day-3-global-ignores and Subversion 1.8 changelog. Show **real output** of `svn pg svn:global-ignores -v`

Comment: @Wrikken - From what I read on it when I discovered it, it can be part of the repository, just like regular `ignore` patterns.  In fact, it's specifically to avoid needing to apply the `svn:ignore` recursively.

Comment: @Bobson:, ah, then I learned something new! I thank you for that ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Note in CollabNet blog-post](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/repository-dictated-configuration-day-3-global-ignores#note-12119-1):

> It was intended that the ignore patterns in the `svn:global-ignores`
>   property could be delimited with any whitespace (similar to the
>   global-ignores runtime configuration option), not just newlines (as
>   with the svn:ignore property), but there is a bug in 1.8.0 and only
>   newline separated patterns work